# Resize div width based on other div width

Tags: html, css

I have an html page. This page has the following structure:

```
<body>
  <div id="div1">....</div>

  <div id="div2">
     <table>...</table>
  </div>

  <div id="div3">....</div>
</body>
```

The div are one beneath the other,they have a border, and their's width are the same.

User can grow the columns of the table, which is inside the div2. In this situation the width of the div1 resized (border grows).
However the other divs' width remain the same. 
How i can make them follow the width of the div2?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, concrete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Can the HTML part be modified? then try put all the `divs` in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div 1 and 3' width is not dependant of div 2 as they are their own boxes, you have to link the boxes somehow (all three are part of body, but body may be bigger than your table at all times so linking their width to body may not work on certain browsers/versions)

Without javascript: create a bigger div that contains div1, 2 and 3, set the width of the other divs to that of the bigger div using CSS, whenever the table grows/shrinks div 2 will grow/shrink and push the boundaries of its parent div. Because div 1 and 3 copy their width from the bigger one, they will grow/shrink as well.

With javascript: Just set the width of the other divs whenever you modify the table's, tables can't be resized usually so you must be using some javascript there

In all cases, research CSS because that's what you will be changing.